# SQL query between and equals

Tags: sql

there are three tables,  first table name is **baseline** which contains all beneficiaries information and one column in the name of *PPI Score* and the second table in the name of **PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP** which contains six columns as below the third table in the name of **endline** which contains beneficiaries end line assessment data and also one column in the name of *PPI_Score*, what i want is, to join some how these tables however there is no foreign key of the **baseline** and  **endline** table in the **PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP** table there is only **PPI_Score** in the tables **PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP**, **endline** and **endline** tables, and i want to query to show some baseline data along PPI result if the values of the ppi in the basline table is between or equals to **PPI_SCORE_START** and **PPI_SCORE_END** and also it should show **endline** data of the same member along with the PPI Score with its six column if ppi score in the **endline** table is between and equals to **PPI_SCORE_START** and **PPI_SCORE_END** all in one row.

Note: i did not try any query yet since i did not have any idea how to do this, but i expect the expected result in the bottom of this question.

Tables are as follows

```
baseline table


ID  NAME    LAST_NAME   DISTRICT    PPI_SCORE
1   A           A          A             10
2   B           B          B             23
3   C           C          C             90
4   D           D          D             47



endline table

baseline_ID       Enterprise    Market  PPI_SCORE
3                  Bee Keeping      Yes 
2                  Poultry          No  74
1                  Agriculture      Yes 80





PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP table

ppi_start   ppi_end national    national_150    national_200    usaid
0              4      100         100                100         100
10             14     66.1        89.5               96.5        39.2
5              9      68.8        90.2               96.7        44.4
15             19     59.5        89.1               97.2        35.2
20             24     51.3        85.5               96.4        28.8
25             29     43.5        81.1               93.2        20
30             34     31.9        74.5               90.4        13.6
35             39     24.6        66.9               87.3        7.9
40             44     15.2        58                 82.8        4.5
45             49     11.4        47.9               73.4        4.2
50             54      6          37.2               68.4        2.6
55             59      2.7        26.1               61.3        0.5
60             64      0.9        21                 50.4        0.5
65             69      0          14.3               37.1        0
70             74      3          14.3               29.2        0
75             79      0          1.4                5.1         0
80             84      0          0                  9.5         0
85             89      0          0                  15.2        0
90             94      0          0                  0           0
95             100     0          0                  0           0
```

Expected Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your query *can* be made in the following way:

```
SELECT *
FROM baseline b
LEFT JOIN endline e ON b.id = e.baseline_ID
LEFT JOIN PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP ppi ON b.PPI_SCORE BETWEEN ppi.ppi_start AND ppi.ppi_end
LEFT JOIN PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP ppi2 ON e.PPI_SCORE BETWEEN ppi2.ppi_start AND ppi2.ppi_end
```

This matches your `id`'s from the `baseline` table with the `baseline_ID`'s from the `endline` table, keeping possible null values from `baseline`. It then matches the `PPI_SCORE` from `baseline` with `ppi_start and ppi_end` from `PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP`. Then we join the `PPI_SCORE` from `endline` with `and ppi_end`.

By replacing * with whatever fields you want to have. 
[See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bf0b/3) for a working example

Comment: Thanks @ewolden what about the endline  along with the ppi scores in the lookup  table will you plz write the complete query

Comment: Did you take a look at the sqlfiddle with my example? Because we join `endline` and `baseline` we just need to join them to `PPI_SCORE_TOOKUP`. Then all 3 tables should be joined. If there are records you see are missing from the result, that you expected to be there, just let me know.

Comment: Let me check it once again

Comment: it works fine with the baseline but does not work with endline i want the lookup table results with the endline ppi score too, will you plz check my expected result picture

Comment: My bad, just realized what you asked for, here is an [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bf0b/3). Will edit the answer to include this as well.

Comment: it is not showing what i have in the expected result, you can check the expected result picture that the endline ppi score is different than the baseline ppi start and end ppi but, your query still shows endline ppi same as baseline result, plz check expected result picture i highlighted three tables with three colors

Comment: It does show different ppi start and end. But regardless, you have seen the query now, and should be able to figure out whatever is missing. I am not here to do your work for you, just to help you in the right direction.

Comment: i created another copy of the ppi lookup table and on for the second endline ppi i used the copied one of the table then it worked like a charm thanks anyway @ewlden for the instruction